# Excel VBA: Index-Match working inconsistently

Tags: excel, vba, userform, worksheet-function

I have an excel userform that pulls data from a worksheet. The user selects an OptionButton next to the textbox (13 total) containing a subject they would like to know additional information about. An index match (worksheet function) then returns the matching data from cells to populate additional textboxes on the userform. 
I have over 100 cells in the worksheet array that can be used to populate the textboxes that have radio buttons next to them. The index-match code I am using works on all of them but five and I cannot figure out why! 
Error code: "Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the Worksheet Class"

I have tried the following:
- making sure all the cells in the array are formatted the same (they are all formatted as 'General'). I have also tried formatting them as 'Text'. No luck
- checking to make sure there were no hidden characters in the cells (I copy/pasted them to a notepad, checked the characters, then copied them back to excel.
- ensured the cells do in fact have matches by copying them to a blank sheet and using the 'check for duplicates'
- I tried to copy the formatting of a cell that does behave correctly onto those that do not.

Here's where it gets strange. 
All the cells contain strings of text that end with something similar to `"<T6-1.1.A.01>"` (not including the quotations) This lets the user know where in the dept reference manual the lines of text came.

For the cells that have match errors, if I delete the contents from the index array and the match array and replace it with some simple text like "apple" the code runs fine. However once I get towards the end and have string that ends in some of the following combinations (including the angle brackets), the code stops working

> <5.A> <.5.A> <5.5.5> <5-1.1.A> <5-1.1,A> <5-1.1 A> <5-1.1A> <5-1 1A>
>
> 5-1.1.A  (no brackets)

This is what my code looks like (for the cases where it works and where it doesn't). The objects I refer to in the code are named ranges from my worksheet. They are all identical lengths.

```
 TextBoxInspection.Text=Application.WorksheetFunction.Index
 (Sheets("Sheet4").Range("InspectionTime"),Application.WorksheetFunction
 .Match(TextBox13.Value,Sheets("Sheet4").Range("InspectionCat"),0),1)
```

I'm pretty new to VBA and cannot figure this one out. Anyone have an idea what is causing this?

Comment: Please create a screenshot with a few rows of data, one row for "it's working" and another one for data that is not working. It's hard to visualise your data structure, especially since the site hides words between angled brackets.

Comment: I was unaware that angle brackets hid text. Sorry about that. If I recall correctly, I cannot upload pictures yet because I do not have enough reputation points

Comment: You can upload a picture but it won't be visible unless someone edits the post. I can do that.